# Managing utf8 CSV on Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, csv, utf-8

I use Excel on macOS and when I try to combine CSV files downloaded from SaaS platforms, it messes things up on the first lines. I don't have this problem when using Excel with Windows.

For now, I have to treat each file individually in order to be able to combine that afterwards but it takes a lot of time compared to Windows.

Is there a way to easily handle UTF-8 CSV files with Excel on Mac?

PS : When combining files, I got this weird "65001" showing up before UTF-8 in the file origin section. Is it relevant to my problem ?

[image: Combining CSV files]

EDIT:To be more precise :
I have multiple csv files, which contain data with accents from different languages (Italian, French, Polish...).

When I open the csv file by double clicking => the characters have encoding issues, the data is not usable.

To have the characters correctly encoded, I am forced to : Open Excel > Import > Select Utf8 > OK.

For every csv file I have, I found no way to :
open any of those csv files with correct encoded characters by just double clicking =>I need to go through the import process.

import and merge multiple csv files, with the right encoding, so I don't have to go through that process for every csv file I have

But on Excel Windows :
no issue of encoding when openning the file

I can use this process Import > Choose a folder (this option doesn't exist on Excel Mac) > csv in the folder are uploaded and rightly encoded > save

Is there any solution to this issue that doesn't require me using Windows or a Windows VM?

Comment: 65001 is Microsoft's code page definition for utf-8 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page

Comment: Thank you for the clarification